# PHP Conditional based on any item within array

Tags: php, conditional-statements, strip-tags

I am using php to extract category names from a series of woocommerce (wordpress) cart items like so:

```
<?php $stack = array();
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $_product = $values['data'];
    $category = $_product->get_categories();
    array_push($stack, $category);              
}
```

If there are two products in the cart, each with a different category, the output of `print_r($stack)` might be: Array ( [0] => Thanksgiving [1] => Poultry )

Regardless of products, I need to run conditional statements like so:

```
if (in_array( 'T-Shirts', $stack[1] )) echo "True"; else echo "False";
```

The above conditional is only looking at the 2nd item in the array, not all. How do I search through all items in array?

Comment: No, you need to remove strip_tags from this code. Don't store html in database.

Comment: Strip tags simply removes the link that is returned from get_categories(); I need it to extract the text from the hyperlink.

Comment: I understand, but it's a very very fragile algorithm.

Comment: Can you suggest any alternate ideas here?

Comment: What does $category contain? echo htmlentities($category); after  $category = $_product->get_categories();

Comment: It contains links to each of the category pages like so:  <a href="linktocategorypage" rel="tag">Category Name</a><a href="linktocategorypage" rel="tag">Category Name</a>

Comment: or if it was just one category it would be: <a href="linktocategorypage" rel="tag">Category Name</a>

Comment: Now that you have all categories in the $stack array, just check change $stack[1] to $stack. I.e. if (in_array( 'T-Shirts', $stack )) echo "True"; else echo "False";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$category = $_product->get_categories();
preg_match_all("`<[^>]+>([^<]+)</[^>]+>`", $category, $categories);
if ( in_array( 'Pants', $categories[1] ) ) {
?>
    <h2>This product has Pants, and potentially other categories</h2>
<?php
}
```

$categories[1] is an array where each element is a single category. in_array() checks to see if the requested value is ANYWHERE in the array.

Test it:

```
$category = '<a href="linktocategorypage" rel="tag">T-Shirts</a><a href="linktocategorypage" rel="tag">Pants</a>';
preg_match_all("`<[^>]+>([^<]+)</[^>]+>`", $category, $categories);
$pants = in_array( 'Pants', $categories[1] );
if ($pants) echo "True"; else echo "False";
print_r($categories[1]);
```

yields:

```
True

Array
(
    [0] => T-Shirts
    [1] => Pants
)
```

**Update**

Integrating with your code:

```
$stack = array();
foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $_product = $values['data'];
    $category = $_product->get_categories();
    preg_match_all("`<[^>]+>([^<]+)</[^>]+>`", $category, $categories);
    foreach( $categories[1] as $cat) $stack[] = $cat;  // Could also use array_merge here
}

if( in_array( 'Pants', $stack ) ) echo 'We have pants';
else echo 'We do not have pants';
```

If you don't want a category to appear more than once in the $stack array:

```
$stack = array();
foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $_product = $values['data'];
    $category = $_product->get_categories();
    preg_match_all("`<[^>]+>([^<]+)</[^>]+>`", $category, $categories);
    foreach( $categories[1] as $cat) {
        if ( !in_array( $cat, $stack ) ) $stack[] = $cat;
    }
}

if( in_array( 'Pants', $stack ) ) echo 'We have pants';
else echo 'We do not have pants';
```

Comment: Thanks. For me, print_r($categories[1]); yields an array with just the first category in the array. It does not return all categories

Comment: What's in your $category string?

Comment: Everything is placed within the foreach statement, correct? The $category string is just what is listed above, the two links

Comment: Because it is within the foreach, it is returning the following:   TrueArray ( [0] => Pants ) FalseArray ( [0] => T-Shirt )

Comment: Can you post your answer with the foreach involved so I can see where you would place the preg_match_all?

Comment: thanks for your help. I restructured my question. Now ,I have all of the category names in an array)